# Shiny update plotOutput brushOpts

Tags: r, shiny

It is possible to control **brushOpts** in **plotOutput** via **input** in ui (like radioButtons). I write a simple code here. The idea is when radioButtons is `"sweeping"`, I want to set **resetOnNew** in **brushOpts** to be `TRUE`
and if radioButtons is `"brushing"`, I want to set **resetOnNew** to be `FALSE`.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
radioButtons("select", "Select type:",  
              choices = c("sweeping", "brushing"), 
              selected = "sweeping"),
plotOutput(outputId="plots",
           brush = brushOpts(id = "plot_brush",
                             resetOnNew = TRUE))
)   

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$plots <-  renderPlot({
     input$plot_brush
     if(input$select == "sweeping")  {
        plot(1:10)       
     } else {
     # input select is "brushing", I want to update 
     # resetOnNew in brushOpts to FALSE, like:

     # brushOpts(id = "plot_brush",
     #           resetOnNew = FALSE)

     plot(10:1)
   }  
 })
} 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```